# Computer won't boot, iwlwifi error

Tags: boot

I ran out of storage recently on my Ubuntu machine, and updated partitions so I have about ~1gb left with a bootable USB. The computer still won't boot but I'm getting the errors on a black screen:

/dev/nvme1n1p4: clean, 1350504/53469184 files, 203267760/213867187 blocks

[ 3.938383] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 WRT: Invalid buffer destination